# Selecting items from layer not within or touching selected polygon using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, select-by-location

Using ArcMap 9.3 I was curious if anybody has a script or vba tool that will select items from a layer that are not within a selected polygon or not touching the selected polygon.

Answer (score 5):

ArcMap has a built-in tool for that: [Select Layer by Location (Data Management)](http://webhelp.esri.com/ARCGISDESKTOP/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Select%20layer%20by%20location%20%28Data%20Management%29).

Just select all features from the Select Layer, then use Select by Location (Data Management) with the overlap type "Intersect" and the selection type "Remove_From_Selection." This will remove from the selection all those that intersect the other layer, and you'll be left with those that do not intersect.

Comment: You can also use the "reverse selection" function in the attribute table to select polygons that do not intersect features from your other layer.